# How to call a function on Twitter Bootstrap in a modal itself?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popup, modal-dialog

I'm using an extention for twitter bootstrap for modals: https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal

I want to call an already defined method that I usually call with the class "event_join". But the function `event_join` only works if I don't have an opened modal.

Now I've tryed the following:

```
$modal.on('click', '.event_join', function(){
   $modal.event_join();
}); 


  $(".event_join").click(function() {
  //my working code
  }
```

But I can't get it to work on an opened modal itself. I just want to use the same function I've already defined.

Comment: the function `event_join` just registers an event handler for the `.event_join` elements. what are you trying to do here

Comment: I want to call the `.event_join` click function

Comment: `$modal.event_join();` will not work as `event_join` is not a method of object `$modal`, you cal simply call `event_join();`.